# Extending SimpleCursor Adapter

Tags: android, gridview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I'm new to android development and i was looking for simplest explanation for using the SimpleCursorAdapter class with a cursorloader for pulling out Video Thumbnails and details from my android device. I'm doing a mini video file browser in my app which i am using a gridView, a Fragment, and some content providers pointing to some external URI. Any form of help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Android training guides.

The guide [Loading Data in the Background](http://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/index.html) shows you how to set up a CursorLoader and use it to get data from a content provider.

The guide [Sending Operations to Multiple Threads](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html) shows you how to do work on a background thread. It includes sample code for downloading, caching, decoding, and displaying images, which is pretty close to what you're doing.

The second guide makes extensive use of Fragments.

I'm not sure what you mean by a content provider that "points to some external URI". Content providers can be backed by *any* type of data, but they're best suited to structured data that exists on the device.

Answer (score 0):

For an example of downloading images in the background, take a look at [here](http://goo.gl/58oXQ).

I used this in a ListView and it works nicely to download images on another thread as well as managing a cache of the images.  Easy callbacks are used and I implemented a view switcher in my list to allow an easy transition from the placeholder image to the real, downloaded image.